# How do I transpose a pandas dataframe while preserving the index and rename keys

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe

This is what I have:

```
df: 
         A    B    C    D
0 foo    1    3    5    7
1 moo    2    4    6    8
2 poo    3    5    7    9
```

What I want:

```
df_Transposed:
         foo    moo   poo 
0    A    1      2     3
1    B    3      4     5
2    C    5      6     7
3    D    7      8     9
```

I tried `transpose()` but my keys became the range of the no. of columns. I want the keys to become `['foo', 'moo', 'poo']`. And I want my index to remain the same as in `df`.

Do not assume square matrix and this is a single index frame.

Comment: Do you have two unnamed indices there? Is it a multi-index dataframe?

Comment: Assuming your index is a MultiIndex, this can only be done if your dataframe is square.

Comment: Single index. Integers on the left.

Comment: What is `foo, moo, poo` if `df` has an integer index? Is it a column with no name? (i.e. a column whose label is an empty string?)

Comment: An Unnamed column. More precisely: `Unnamed: 1` column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to do it another way. Here's my code. After transposing:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.reset_index()
df = df.drop(df.index[0])
df = df.reset_index()
df =df.drop(["level_0","index"],axis = 1)
```

Comment: I would just add "df.to_excel(location, sheet_name)" so that it takes effect.

Answer (score 2):

You could transpose, and then use [`droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.droplevel.html) to remove the extra column level

```
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
```

and use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to add a new index level:

```
result = result.set_index([np.arange(len(result)), result.index])
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(0, 'foo'), (1, 'moo'), (2, 'poo')])
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                   'B': [3, 4, 5],
                   'C': [5, 6, 7],},
                  index=index)

result = df.T
result.columns = result.columns.droplevel(0)
result = result.set_index([np.arange(len(result)), result.index])
print(result)
```

prints

```
     foo  moo  poo
0 A    1    2    3
1 B    3    4    5
2 C    5    6    7
```

Answer (score 1):

#### One liner (and gross)

```
df.reset_index(0, drop=True).T.set_index([range(len(df.columns))], append=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
```

#### Less gross

```
df1 = df.reset_index(0, drop=True).T
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    zip(range(len(df1)), df1.index.tolist())
)
df1 = df1.set_index(idx)
df1
```

#### Both produce

[image]

Comment: Interesting in pandas 0.18 i get an KeyError with the set_index step of `KeyError: range(0,3)`

Comment: @Grr: In Python3 you might need to use `list(range(len(df1)))` instead of `range(len(df1))` since `range(...)` returns a `range` object.

Comment: That's why I `[range(len(df1))]`

Comment: I had tried it that way and by hardcoding the list in myself as [0,1,2]. Neither way worked. Trying `list(range(len(df1))) also returns a keyerror

Comment: My frame is not a square. The transposed frame has 363 rows. I'm sorry about the confusion. I didn't fathom the shape would be important. 
Also, I only have one index.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to piRSquared's answer, but with a different way of changing the index.

```
df1 = df.reset_index.(0, drop=True).T
df1.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(df1.index)])
```

This will work for dataframes that aren't square as well as those that are square.

Answer (score 1):

This somewhat works, I couldnt find a way to drop labels(['level_0', 'index']) from multiIndex.

```
    df3 = df.reset_index(0, drop=True).T.reset_index().reset_index()
    df3 = df3.set_index(['level_0', 'index'])
    df3

                       foo  moo  poo
     level_0 index               
       0       A        1    2    3
       1       B        3    4    5
       2       C        5    6    7
       3       D        7    8    9

df3.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 4 entries, (0, A) to (3, D)
Data columns (total 3 columns):
foo    4 non-null int64
moo    4 non-null int64
poo    4 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(3)
memory usage: 128.0+ bytes
```

Comment: I did the same thing. Or somewhat similar. I'll post my code as an answer.